# Easily scrap large amounts of gear

Tags: fallout-4

I have beaten the game, and am now building settlements. Vendors don't have enough money to buy even a fraction of the gear(weapons, ammunition, armor, mods) I collect on the average building clear, even with buying ammo and fusion cores. I've been scrapping gear by dropping it on the floor, then using settlement mode to dismantle each object, but this is slow and frustrating. I've tried scrapping containers full of gear, but this just puts it in the workshop. Is there a way to scrap large amounts of gear easily, either in vanilla or by a mod?

Comment: Because I can't sell it to merchants for lack of caps on their part. I guess i could not pick it up, but I use looted bodies to tell where i am in a building. I also kinda just like looting :/

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I will clarify in the OP. I mean guns, ammo, mods, and armor.

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense. On board.

Comment: Have you tried dropping and scrapping stacks of items?

Comment: Hmm, by right clicking the stack? I *think* it drops them 1 by 1, but I'll definitely try again when I get home.

Comment: I know for certain that I've dropped stacks of road leathers and raider leathers to scrap all at once.

Comment: Awesome! Can you post that as an answer so i can select it if it works?

Comment: You can scrap armor and weapons at the armor and weapons workbenches.  I believe there's just a button press to scrap once you select the item you want, so you could probably scrap those very quickly.  With junk, go to the workbench and select store all junk.  The junk won't be scrapped, but it will get broken down to be used as scrap automatically as you build.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't mind using the console, you can:

1. Take the items to a settlement where you haven't built anything yet (or where you won't miss anything that gets scrapped), and drop them on the ground.
2. Enter and then exit settlement mode.
3. Open the console and use the `scrapall` command.
   **NOTE**

   > From http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_console_commands
   >   Warning: scrapall Must be used only after entering and exiting the settlement mode of that area - do this every time you use this command or several items in other areas may also be scrapped. Things like doors to other cells, the doors to the basement in The Castle for an example. You will be unable to enter these areas if they are deleted. Be very careful when using this.

All scrappable items within the settlement boundaries will be scrapped and the resulting components stored in the workbench for you to retrieve.

Comment: Gawd, i wish i had known that command when i was clearing settlements. Are there any particularly tiny, boring settlements I can scrap all on?

Comment: There's probably a smaller one, but I just went to Outpost Zimonja to test whether weapons and armor get scrapped with this process. It's fairly small, but you need to have cleared first.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if I'd call this *easy*, but maybe *easier*.

If you have multiple identical items, they will stack in your inventory. This is indicated by a number in parentheses after the item. You can drop stacks, and then scrap them all at once in workshop mode. There may be a limit to the size of the stack you can scrap at once, but I haven't done enough experimentation to say for sure if that's the case or how large it can get.

Items in your inventory begin acting as stacks when there are 6 of them. If you have 5 harnesses, and you click to sell them to a vendor, it sells one and reduces the stack to 4. If you have 6 harnesses and click to sell one, a dialog comes up asking you how many you want to sell. This same thing happens if you try to drop them. So, if you wait until you have a stack of at least 6, you can drop and scrap the whole stack at once.

Comment: Or is it six? Just was re-reading this while looking for duplicates, five is from memory. I'll double check that.

Comment: It's 6.  I'm playing it right now.

Comment: @Nelson Yep. I confirmed last night as well.